# Getting the max value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So these is how my key value looks like

```
    dict_info = {}
    dict_info['math 12345'] = 10
    dict_info['math 1234'] = 2
    dict_info['math 123'] = 1
    dict_info['SCI 124'] = 16
    dict_info['SCI 345'] = 2
```

So there I have five different dictionaries. However what I want to do is make sure I compare the first letter before space for instance I have 3 math there and 2 SCI. I just want to get the highest value of 10 which represents MATH 12345. And get 16 which represents SCI 124 and skip the rest. So all I want is the highest value of classes called math and SCI. And get rid of the ones that is less in value. So far my code looks like this. I couldn't figure the syntax.

```
def check_if_works():
    import operator
    dict_info = {}
    dict_info['math 12345'] = 10
    dict_info['math 1234'] = 2
    dict_info['math 123'] = 1
    dict_info['SCI 124'] = 16
    dict_info['SCI 345'] = 2
    for key, value in dict_info.iteritems():
        arr = key.split(' ')
        class_first_letters_only = arr[0]
        if class_first_letters_only == arr[0]:



check_if_works()
```

@user161151
Here is the code but it prints me all the duplicates in my json file.

```
for key,value in new_dictionary.iteritems():
                                            #print key
                                            k = key.split()[0]
                                            full_info = k + ' ' + key.split()[-1]
                                            print full_info
                                            if ans.get(k,0) < value:
                                                ans[k] = value

                                        #print new_dictionary
                                                sort_info = sorted(ans.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
                                                first_20 = sort_info[:20]       

        with open('output_1.json','wb') as outfile:
                json.dump(first_20,outfile,indent=4)
```

**I'd like to also as for my output would want full key name instead of just prefix like MATH i'd want MATH 12345 : 16. Also I'd like to save my output to a json file where it's sorted from max to minimum value pair.**
@Jankos Frankas

```
for key, value in new_dictionary.iteritems():
                                            try:
                                                if result[key.split()[0]] < value:
                                                    result[key.split()[0]] = value
                                                    keys[key.split()[0]] = key
                                            except KeyError:
                                                result[key.split()[0]] = value
                                                keys[key.split()[0]] = key
                                        #replace the key prefixes with full length key
                                        for key in keys.keys():
                                            result[keys[key]] = result.pop(key)
                                        #return result
                        with open('output_check_123.json','wb') as outfile:
                            outfile.write(json.dumps(new_dictionary,indent=4))
```

There's the code.

Comment: No - there you have __one__ dictionary. You have 5 key value pairs inside your one dictionary.

Comment: Yes. I have a dictionary with 5 key value pairs. So what I want to do is go through my keys and make sure I get the highest value for each same string and resave them in a new dictionary.

Comment: If you want to group the values by part of a key, you should probably have another level of nesting/organization.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I just want to go through my key. Get rid of the other classes that has the same name and get the highest value of each key. So in this case I'd just have two key value which is Math 12345 : 10 and SCI : 16

Comment: I understand that. My point is that instead of looking at bits and pieces of a key, you should create this dictionary with more separate keys, e.g. `{'math':{'12345':10, '1234':2, '123':1}, 'SCI':{'124':16, '345':2}}`.

Comment: The dictionary above I showed was just an example of how my dictionary looks. So like I want to figure out a way with how my dictionary is presented instead of changing the formatting.

Comment: [
    [
        "ENGR 1", 
        16
    ], 
    [
        "MATH 53", 
        14
    ], 
    [
        "MATH 98", 
        9
    ], 
    [
        "UGBA 102", 
        7
    ], 
    [
        "MBA 202", 
        7
    ], 
    [
        "MATH 198", 
        6
    ], 
    [
        "BIOE 10", 
        6
    ], 
    That's how actually my dictionary looks like in a json file. So basically I just want to get the highest value of a key. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Will it not be helpful to just make it recursive?

Answer (score 2):

Returns the maximum values of every unique first word in the keys of `dict_info` as a dictionary of the key with the maximum value corresponding to that first word in `dict_info`.

```
def get_max_groups(dict_info):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dict_info.iteritems():
        sub_key = key.split()[0]
        match_keys = filter(lambda ikey: ikey.split()[0] == sub_key, result)
        if not match_keys:
            result[key] = value
            continue
        m = match_keys[0]
        if result[m] < value:
            del result[m]
            ans[key] = value
    return ans
```

Comment: Perfect! One last question. So this returns me just "math" and "SCI" with their highest value. What if I wanted the full name such as "MATH 12345" : 10 and "SCI 124" : 16

Comment: @Benji Use `key` as key in `ans` instead of `k`.

Comment: I tried that and it actually prints me the duplicates when I change from k to key. It gives me MATH 12345, MATH 1234 and MATH 123

Comment: @Benji But wasn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Actually I'd want the full key string instead of the prefix only. That's what I actually want. I'm trying to save it to a json file where I have maximum value to minimum value with full key string.

Comment: @user161161 Apologies about that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with some [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
dict_info = {}
dict_info['math 12345'] = 10
dict_info['math 1234'] = 2
dict_info['math 123'] = 1
dict_info['SCI 124'] = 16
dict_info['SCI 345'] = 2

def check_if_works(dictionary):
    math_max = max([dictionary[key] for key in dictionary if key.startswith('math')])
    sci_max = max([dictionary[key] for key in dictionary if key.startswith('SCI')])
    return math_max, sci_max


print check_if_works(dict_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def check_if_works():
    import operator
    dict_info = {}
    dict_info['math 12345'] = 10
    dict_info['math 1234'] = 2
    dict_info['math 123'] = 1
    dict_info['SCI 124'] = 16
    dict_info['SCI 345'] = 2
    result={}
    for key, value in dict_info.iteritems():
        try:
            if result[key.split()[0]] < value:
                result[key.split()[0]] = value
        except KeyError:
            result[key.split()[0]] = value

    return result



dict_info = check_if_works()
print dict_info
```

now  `dict_info` equals:

> {'SCI': 16, 'math': 10}

if you want the full length key, not only the "prefix" use this code:

```
def check_if_works():
    import operator
    dict_info = {}
    dict_info['math 12345'] = 10
    dict_info['math 1234'] = 2
    dict_info['math 123'] = 1
    dict_info['SCI 124'] = 16
    dict_info['SCI 345'] = 2
    result={}
    keys = {}
    for key, value in dict_info.iteritems():
        try:
            if result[key.split()[0]] < value:
                result[key.split()[0]] = value
                keys[key.split()[0]] = key
        except KeyError:
            result[key.split()[0]] = value
            keys[key.split()[0]] = key
    #replace the key prefixes with full length key
    for key in keys.keys():
        result[keys[key]] = result.pop(key)
    return result



dict_info = check_if_works()
print dict_info
```

resul:

> {'math 12345': 10, 'SCI 124': 16}

Comment: What if I wanted the key full string such as "SCI 124" and "MATH 12345"

Comment: Hey it gives me duplicates in my json file when I try an save it like this.
with open('output_1.json','wb') as outfile:
                                            json.dump(result,outfile,indent=4)

Comment: try like this: open("result.json",'w').write(json.dumps(dict_info))

Comment: The actual code isn't under a function but is underneath if __name__ == "__main__". I tried that it didn't work. I put it under function so it's easier for people to understand. And also dict_info is just an example. My actual code is already in a dictionary that is formatted like dict_info.

Comment: So I'm trying to use your code and save it into a json file which is sorted from max value to minimum value with full key string.

Comment: new_dictionary[final_output]=value
                                        for key, value in new_dictionary.iteritems():
                                            try:
                                                if result[key.split()[0]] < value:
                                                    result[key.split()[0]] = value
                                                    keys[key.split()[0]] = key
That's how my actual main code looks like

Comment: use with open('output_1.json','wb') as outfile:
                outfile.write(json.dumps(dict_info,indent=4)) instad of with open('output_1.json','wb') as outfile:
                json.dump(first_20,outfile,indent=4), and there will be no duplicates

Comment: In my actual code not the one that I showed in this thread. I did with open('output_check_123.json','wb') as outfile:
                            outfile.write(json.dumps(new_dictionary,indent=4))
I dumped 'new_dictionary' because that represents the dictionary. It still gave me duplicates. 
I'll add the code in the main thread to show you how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_duplicates(dict_info):
    import operator

    result={}
    keys = {}
    for key, value in dict_info.iteritems():
        try:
            #print result[key.split()[0]]
            if result[key.split()[0]] < value:
                result[key.split()[0]] = value
                keys[key.split()[0]] = key
        except KeyError:
            result[key.split()[0]] = value
            keys[key.split()[0]] = key
    #replace the key prefixes with full length key
    for key in keys.keys():
        result[keys[key]] = result.pop(key)
    return result
```

This worked great thanks to @Jankos. I added an argument called dict_info where I can just use this function to make it work under my main script which has the same formatting of dictionary as presented. Now it works flawlessly, thank you!